# Android custom XML parser fails to resolve android namespace

Tags: android, string, xml-namespaces, xmlpullparser

I would like to get the correct way of parsing custom android tags with an XmlResourceParser. I am using Eclipse 3.6 with the android plug-in, and I would like some attributes like the `name` be expanded with the full string from `strings.xml`.

Here is the `index.xml` which is being parsed in the `res/xml/` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Index xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Sheet
    shortName="o_2sq"
    android:name="@string/o_2sq"
    instructions=""
/>
</Index>
```

Here is the file `strings.xml` in the `res/values/` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="o_2sq">Organize two squares</string>
</resources>
```

and the code fragment that parses the first `index.xml` with an XmlResourceParser:

```
String name = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "android:name");
String shortName = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "shortName");
```

The variable `name` contains `null`, but `shortName` contains `"o_2sq"`. I also tried the following without success:

```
String name = xpp.getAttributeValue("android", "name");
```

What is the correct way of writing the sentence so that the variable name would contain `"Organize two squares"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution I found to overcome that problem.

```
String s = xpp.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "name");
String name = null;
if(s != null && s.length() > 1 && s.charAt(0) == '@') {
  int id = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1));
  name = getString(id);
} else {
  name = "";
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `else { name = s' }` ?  Seems like that would allow that attribute to be either a resource or a hard-coded string, no?

Comment: I needed name to be not null in my case. This is why.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
String name = xpp.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "name");
```

Comment: Nice try. It gives something better : my variable `name` now contains the string `"@2131099651"`. Not sure why.

Comment: It is probably string resource ID. Try to use getString( number ); method to get string.

Answer (score 2):

```
final String NAMESPACE_ANDROID = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
final int VALUE_NOT_SET = -1;
int resId = parser.getAttributeResourceValue(NAMESPACE_ANDROID, "name", VALUE_NOT_SET);
String value = null;
if (VALUE_NOT_SET != resId) {
    value = context.getString(resId);
}
```

I think the above code could help you.